# Spring AOP, @JaversAuditable still trying to commit a change when exception has been thrown

Tags: spring, spring-data, javers

This is with Spring 4.1.9.RELEASE, Spring-Data 1.11.4.RELEASE, Javers 1.6.0 with spring integration

So using Spring with `@JaversAuditable`, I'm finding that if an exception handles when I try and insert (such as duplicate key exception), `JaversTransactionalDecorator` still goes ahead and tries to generate a commit.

However, since my entity doesn't have an ID due to the failed insert, Javers ends up throwing an exception (see below). Stepping through debug, I'm finding in I end up in `org.springframework.aop.aspectjAspectJAfterAdvice.invoke()` in the finally block. It then calls `invokeAdviceMethod(JoinPointMatch,null,null)`, with that 3rd `null` being a spot for a `Throwable`.

According to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html, `@After` advice will run as a finally, regardless if the method exists normally or with an exception. Thus, it sounds like Javers needs to be able to be able to detect if an exception has been thrown, or use a different Advice like `@AfterReturning`, possibly with a separate `@AfterThrowing`. I'm trying to find out in the current `@After` that Javers has ( `org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.JaversAuditableRepositoryAspect.commitAdvice(JoinPoint pjp)` ) how it'd be able to detect if an exception/throwable has been thrown, but I can't seem to find anything in the docs about that.

So, is this something Javers already has but for some reason it's not correctly picking up on the thrown SQL exception, or where would some info on detecting in `@After` advice the thrown exception/throwable so I could go in and contribute a fix for this?

Sorry for the possibly less than extremely organized, I'm here a couple hours past normal time.

```
Caused by: org.javers.common.exception.JaversException: ENTITY_INSTANCE_WITH_NULL_ID Found Entity instance of class 'com.findology.api.model.publisher.Publisher' with null id
at org.javers.core.metamodel.type.EntityType.getIdOf(EntityType.java:96)
at org.javers.core.metamodel.object.InstanceId.createFromInstance(InstanceId.java:28)
at org.javers.core.metamodel.object.GlobalIdFactory.createId(GlobalIdFactory.java:47)
at org.javers.core.graph.LiveCdoFactory.create(LiveCdoFactory.java:24)
at org.javers.core.graph.LiveCdoFactory.create(LiveCdoFactory.java:9)
at org.javers.core.graph.EdgeBuilder.asCdo(EdgeBuilder.java:39)
at org.javers.core.graph.ObjectGraphBuilder.buildGraph(ObjectGraphBuilder.java:45)
at org.javers.core.graph.LiveGraphFactory.createLiveGraph(LiveGraphFactory.java:39)
at org.javers.core.commit.CommitFactory.create(CommitFactory.java:76)
at org.javers.core.JaversCore.commit(JaversCore.java:70)
at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator.commit(JaversTransactionalDecorator.java:52)
at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$acb40bd0.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:718)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
at org.javers.spring.jpa.JaversTransactionalDecorator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c6591394.commit(<generated>)
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.JaversCommitAdvice.commitMethodArguments(JaversCommitAdvice.java:24)
at org.javers.spring.auditable.aspect.JaversAuditableRepositoryAspect.commitAdvice(JaversAuditableRepositoryAspect.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:603)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterAdvice.java:46)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
at com.findology.api.dao.PublisherDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8ba00510.insert(<generated>)
at com.findology.api.controller.SimpleController.createPublisher(SimpleController.java:82)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:775)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:965)
... 74 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, final resolution is changing to use @AfterReturning as per Spring docs, it's in the process of being accepted as per https://github.com/javers/javers/pull/356, so a future version will incorporate the fix.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, @JaversAuditable shouldn't call javers.commit() when an exception has been thrown from a repository method beeing adviced. Could you come up with a PR which will fix this in JaVers (using 'on success' pointcut, maybe @AfterReturning like you have mentioned) ?

Comment: Sure, I'll see if I can get to this today and send a PR.

Comment: Fix is released in JaVers 1.6.2